# Long exact sequence induced by another long exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Assume that $0\to A_{\bullet}\to^{f} B_{\bullet}\to^g C_{\bullet}\to0$ is a short exact sequence of complexes of $R$-modules where $R$ is a commutative ring. This induces a homology exact sequence

$$\cdots\to H_{n}(A_{\bullet})\xrightarrow{f_*} H_{n}(B_{\bullet})\xrightarrow{g_*}H_{n}(C_{\bullet})\xrightarrow{\partial} H_{n-1}(A_{\bullet})\to\cdots,~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$

where $f_*$, $g_*$ are the induced morphisms on homology and $\partial$ is the connecting morphism. Assume further that for every $n$, we have isomorphisms of $R$-modules $\phi_n: H_{n}(B_{\bullet})\cong H_n(D_{\bullet})$ and $\psi_n: H_n(C_{\bullet})\cong H_n(E_{\bullet})$.

Is it correct that the long exact sequence $(1)$ induces a long exact sequence of $R$-modules:

$$\cdots\to H_{n}(A_{\bullet})\xrightarrow{\phi_n\circ f_*} H_{n}(D_{\bullet})\xrightarrow{\psi_n\circ g_*\circ\phi_n^{-1}}H_{n}(E_{\bullet})\xrightarrow{\partial\circ\psi_n^{-1}} H_{n-1}(A_{\bullet})\to\cdots?~~~~~~~(2)$$

I believe yes and here is a simple proof why:

**Proof:**

A short computation demonstrates that at $H_n(D_{\bullet})$, we have:
$$\ker(\psi_n\circ g_*\circ\phi_n^{-1})=(\phi_n^{-1})^{-1}(\ker(\psi_n\circ g_*))=\phi_n(g_*^{-1}(\ker(\psi_n)))=\phi_n(g_*^{-1}(0))=\phi_n(\ker g_*),$$
$$Im(\phi_n\circ f_*)=\phi_n(Im(f_*)).$$

From the exactness of the sequence $(1)$, we have $Im (f_*)=\ker(g_*)$. Hence, $\phi_n(Im(f_*))=\phi_n(\ker g_*)$. Hence, sequence $(2)$ is exact at $H_n(D_{\bullet})$.

Similarly, at $H_n(E_{\bullet})$, we have

$$Im(\psi_n\circ g_*\circ\phi_n^{-1})=\psi_n(g_*(H_n(B_{\bullet})))=\psi_n(Im(g_*)),$$
$$\ker(\partial\circ\psi_n^{-1})=\psi_n(\ker(\partial))$$.

Again, the exactness of $(1)$ implies $\psi_n(Im(g_*))=\psi_n(\ker(\partial))$. Hence, sequence (2) is exact at $H_n(E_{\bullet})$.

Finally, at $H_{n-1}(A_{\bullet})$, we have:

$$Im(\partial\circ\psi_n^{-1})=\partial(H_n(C_{\bullet}))=Im(\partial),$$
$$\ker(\phi_{n-1}\circ f_*)=f_*^{-1}(\ker(\phi_{n-1}))=f_*^{-1}(0)=\ker(f_*).$$

Hence, the exactness of sequence $(1)$ at $H_{n-1}(A_{\bullet})$ implies the exactness of sequence $(2)$ at $H_{n-1}(A_{\bullet})$.

On the basis of the above verification, I conclude that sequence $(2)$ is exact.    **QED**

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the short exact sequence. Given any infinite exact sequence, we can substitute in any isomorphic module at any point in the sequence this way.

Comment: So if $U\to V\to W$ is exact and $V\cong V',$ we have a $U\to V'\to W$ exact as well, for suitable definitions of these two new maps.

Comment: To be more specific, if $f:U\to V, g:V\to W$ and $\phi:V\cong V'$ we have $f'=\phi\circ f:U\to V', $ $g'=g\circ \phi^{-1}$ has $ker(f')=ker(f), im(g')=im(g)$ and $U\to V'\to W$ exact.

Comment: In particular, you can plug in any isomorphic sequences into the long exact sequence - there is no reason for them to be homologies $H_n(D_*).$ They could be any sequence $U_n$ of $R$-modules isomorphic to $H_n(B_*).$

Comment: Thank you, I agree with your comments. Repeating the same procedure at $H_n(C_*)$ and replacing it by a module $W_n$ isomorphic to $H_n(C_*)$, we get a long exact sequence $\cdots\to H_n(A_*)\to U_n\to W_n\to H_{n-1}(A_*)\to\cdots$. Then we can repeat again the same for $H_n(A_*)$, till we get an entirely new long exact sequence $\cdots\to V_n\to U_n\to W_n\to V_{n-1}\to\cdots$, right?